# Estimating transaction gas JS

Tags: ethers.js, gas-estimate

I am using ethers js version 6.9.1 with a node js
I I am trying to estimate the gas for calling a function called `createView` in my smart contract, so I used this code:

```
const amount = ethers.parseEther("0.01")    

contract.createView.estimateGas(amount);
```

However, when I run my script, I get the following error

```
Error estimating gas: no matching fragment (operation="fragment", info={ "args": [ 10000000000000000 ], "key": "createView" }, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.9.1)
Error: missing revert data (action="estimateGas", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data": "0x7255d729", "from": "MY_WALLET ADDRESS", "to": "MY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS" }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.9.1)

    at makeError (C:\Users\xxx\xxx\JS CODES\Test folder\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:129:21)  
    at getBuiltinCallException (C:\Users\xxx\xxx\JS CODES\Test folder\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\abi-coder.js:104:37)  
    at AbiCoder.getBuiltinCallException (C:\Users\xxx\xxx\JS CODES\Test folder\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\abi-coder.js:201:16)  
    at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (C:\Users\xxx\xxx\JS CODES\Test folder\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js:668:43)  
    at C:\Users\sendt\Documents\TG Bot\Test folder\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js:302:45  
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',  
  action: 'estimateGas',  
  data: null,  
  reason: null,  
  transaction: {  
    to: 'MY_CONTRACT ADDRESS',  
    data: '0x7255d729',  
    from: 'MY_WALLET_ADDRESS'  
  },  
  invocation: null,  
  revert: null,  
  shortMessage: 'missing revert data',  
  info: {  
    error: { code: -32000, message: 'execution reverted' },  
    payload: {  
      method: 'eth_estimateGas',  
      params: [Array],  
      id: 40,  
      jsonrpc: '2.0'  
    } 
  }  
}
```